# C++ What is the std::for_each() function parameter type?

Tags: c++, function, foreach, functor

Here are a couple of snippets from my first successful use of the std::for_each() construct:

```
struct add_to_memory {
    void operator()(const boost::tuple<const string&, const string&> &t ) {
        m_map.insert(make_pair(t.get<0>(),t.get<1>()));
    }
    add_to_memory(MemoryBank &m) : m_map(m) {};
private:
    MemoryBank &m_map;
};

void
memorize(Block &block) {
    block.get_record_types(record_type_set);
    BOOST_FOREACH(D_RecordType_Set::value_type rec_type, record_type_set) {
        MD_Zip_Range zipper = block.make_field_value_zip_range(rec_type);
        std::for_each(zipper.first, zipper.second, add_to_memory(memory_bank));
    }
}
```

I now want to change "memorize" into a function that accepts an additional parameter - a function or functor or whatever it is `add_to_memory()` is.  But I can't figure out what type to use in the signature.

```
void scan_block_and_apply_function( Block&, ..?.. );
```

I'm using [*read:* "stuck with"] g++ 4.4, so it's safe to say I haven't got c++11.  What should the signature be?  And how should scan_block_and_apply_function() be called?

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done through templates:

```
template <typename MemoryBankFunctor>
void memorize(Block &block, MemoryBankFunctor functor) {
    block.get_record_types(record_type_set);
    BOOST_FOREACH(D_RecordType_Set::value_type rec_type, record_type_set) {
        MD_Zip_Range zipper = block.make_field_value_zip_range(rec_type);
        std::for_each(zipper.first, zipper.second, functor);
    }
}
```

Comment: `F(memory_bank)`?  you mean `functor` ?

Comment: @Chap: Correct... I forgot to think before typing :)

Comment: I should have asked for this originally, but - can you also show how memorize() would be called?

Comment: @Chap: `memorize(block,add_to_memory(memory_bank))` [Note that there are copies of the argument being done here, and potentially inside `for_each`, your implementation of `add_to_memory` would have to deal with this (i.e. calling the functor or a copy of the functor should have the same effect). This basically means that the state must be managed outside of the functor itself --as you are doing by holding a reference]

Comment: Still confused.. the prototype for memorize would be `void memorize(Block&, ..?..);` ?  (Sorry - this is amazingly hard to grasp.)

Comment: Ah! the whole template goes into the .h file.  No need for additional prototype.

Comment: It is not *that* hard with some experience. The important thing is that you want one of the arguments to be of a type you don't know, so you tell the compiler this is a template for which I don't yet know the type of `T` (`MemoryBankFunctor` in this case). Later I will tell you, or maybe you can even infer it from the context. The syntax is like a regular function `void memorize(Block &block, F functor)` except that you tell it, well, `F` is not really a type I know of... consider the code to be a pattern (template) from which generate the function: `template <typename F> ...`

Answer (score 0):

What you're passing is an instance of `add_to_memory`. So something like this should do:

```
void memorize(Block &block, add_to_memory func)
{
    // ...
    std::for_each(zipper.first, zipper.second, func);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a templated parameter:

```
    template <typename T>
    void scan_block_and_apply_function( Block&, const T& );
```

This will allow you to use any kind of functor or function